# collection_select not inserting value from other model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collection-select

I have two models, `Roaster` and `Roast`

I want to have the user select the value of  `:roaster` in the new roast form, from the `Roaster` model.  I am using a collection_select which displays the list of roasters in the dropdown ok, but it doesn't insert the value into the table. From the console, it actually looks like it's trying to pass the `roaster_id`

```
"roast"=>{"roaster_id"=>"1", "name"=>"Rugby", "beans"=>"", "countries_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"country_name"=>"", "regions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"region_name"=>""}}}, "1"=>{"country_name"=>"", "regions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"region_name"=>""}}}, "2"=>{"country_name"=>"", "regions_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"region_name"=>""}}}}, "bestfor"=>"", "roast"=>"", "tastingnotes"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Roast"}
```

My select:

```
<%= form.collection_select(:roaster_id, Roaster.all, :id, :roaster_name, :prompt => 'Select Roaster') %>
```

I've tried

```
<%= form.collection_select(:roaster_name, Roaster.all, :id, :roaster_name, :prompt => 'Select Roaster') %>
```

but this gives and undefined method error.

My roast_params

```
params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster, :roaster_id, :name, :bestfor, :beans, :roast, :tastingnotes, :notes, :slug, :avatar, countries_attributes: [:country_id, :country_name, regions_attributes: [:id, :region_name]])
```

Adding in `:roaster_name` doesn't solve either.

As requested full form:

```
<%= form_with(model: roast, local: true, multipart: true) do |form| %>
  <% if roast.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
      <h2><%= pluralize(roast.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this roast from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% roast.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% end %>

<form>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="field form-group">
      <%= form.label :roaster, class: 'control-label' %>
      <%= form.collection_select(:roaster_id, Roaster.all, :id, :roaster_name, :prompt => 'Select Roaster') %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label :name, class: 'control-label' %>
      <%= form.text_field :name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :beans, "Blend", class: 'control-label' %><br />
    <%= form.select :beans, [ 'Single Origin','Two Country Blend', 'Three Country Blend' ], :prompt => 'Select One', id: :roast_beans, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

<div class="row">
  <%= form.fields_for :countries do |countries_form| %>
  <div class="col-6">

    <div class="form-group">

        <%= countries_form.label :country %>
        <%= countries_form.text_field :country_name, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
  <!-- note the appending of `countries_`  to form.fields to allow for deeper nested to work-->
        <%= countries_form.fields_for :regions do |regions_form| %>
          <%= regions_form.label :region %>
          <%= regions_form.text_field :region_name, class: "form-control" %>
        <% end %>
        <br />
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :bestfor, "Style", class: 'control-label' %><br />
    <%= form.select :bestfor, [ 'Espresso','Filter' ], :prompt => 'Select One', id: :roast_bestfor, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :roast, "Strength", class: 'control-label' %><br />
    <%= form.select :roast, [ 'Light','Medium','Dark' ], :prompt => 'Select One', id: :roast_roast, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :tastingnotes, "Tasting Notes (separate with commas, e.g chocolate, citrus)", class: 'control-label' %><br  />
    <%= form.text_area :tastingnotes, id: :roast_tastingnotes, class: "form-control" %>
  </div>
<br />

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :avatar, "Upload image...", class: 'control-label' %>
    <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit class: "btn btn-success" %> <%= link_to "Cancel", "/roasts", class: "btn btn-secondary"%>
  </div>
<% end %>

</form>
```

**roast_controller.rb**

```
class RoastsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_roast, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_search

  # GET /roasts
  # GET /roasts.json
  def index
      @q = Roast.ransack(params[:q])
      @roastsalpha = @q.result.order(:name)
      @roastcount = Roast.count(:country)
      @roasts = Roast.order(:name).count
      @countroastschart = Roast.order("roaster DESC").all

  end

  # GET /roasts/1
  # GET /roasts/1.json
  def show
    @roast = Roast.friendly.find(params[:id])
    @commentable = @roast
    @comments = @commentable.comments
    @comment = Comment.new
    @sameroaster = Roast.where(roaster: @roast.roaster)
    @samecountry = Roast.where(country: @roast.country)
    @roastcount = Roast.where(roaster: @roast.roaster)



  end

  # GET /roasts/new
  def new
    @roast = Roast.new
    3.times {@roast.countries.build.regions.build}
  end

  # GET /roasts/1/edit
  def edit
    3.times {@roast.countries.build.regions.build}
  end

  # POST /roasts
  # POST /roasts.json
  def create
    @roast = Roast.new(roast_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @roast.save
        format.html { redirect_to @roast, notice: 'Roast was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @roast }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /roasts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /roasts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @roast.update(roast_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @roast, notice: 'Roast was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @roast }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @roast.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /roasts/1
  # DELETE /roasts/1.json
  def destroy
    @roast.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to roasts_url, notice: 'Roast was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_roast
      @roast = Roast.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def roast_params
      params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster, :roaster_id, :name, :bestfor, :beans, :roast, :tastingnotes, :notes, :slug, :avatar, countries_attributes: [:country_id, :country_name, regions_attributes: [:id, :region_name]])
    end

end
```

Comment: can you please post the full form present in ERB and also the controller side code too

Comment: I've justed added the new form.  What is it your looking for in the rest of it?

Comment: Did u you check roast.valid? in new method in controller. Once you check valid? you will see the error message at the top where you have checked  roast.errors.full_messages

Comment: Yes, it tells me 'roaster` cannot be blank.  Which makes sense as I can see I am not passing a value.

Comment: I suspect you have belongs_to: roaster in Roast model and Roast model has roaster_id as column

Comment: I had a spelling mistake on belongs_to !  I have now been able to create a new record, but it saves not the name but this `Roaster:0x007f94948c0d68`

Comment: You should post the  controller where the roast is created. The params are passed ok, so the controller must be doing something wrong. Why do you have tags <form> and </form> inside the form_with?

Comment: I've just added my roasts_controller if that's what you meant.  Yes, those <form> tags needn't be there and I've removed them.

Comment: Does it still fail to save after you corrected the typo? What's the error now?

Comment: I'm able to create a new record but it doesn't save name but this Roaster:0x007f94948c0d68

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are doing many wrong things. By looking your other questions I saw your models. I put some important things:

```
class Roast < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :countries
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :countries
end

class Country < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :regions, inverse_of: :country
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :regions
  belongs_to :roast
end

class Region < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :country, inverse_of: :regions
end
```

In these models I didn't see the Roaster. I assume a `Roast belongs_to :roaster`.

So: your **Roast has many countries** and each **country has many regions**. But you are passing country names and region names in your view to the create controller. You need to pass the ids, so that you save references to these models.

You have many unnecessary field in params, and some missing ones. This is how it should be:

```
def roaster_params
  params.require(:roast).permit(:roaster_id, :name, :bestfor, :beans, :tastingnotes, :notes, :slug, :avatar, countries_attributes: [:id, regions_attributes: [:id]])
end
```

*You don't need roast, roaster, country_name, region_name. You need the id of the country (and not the country_id), and the id of the region (and not the region_id)*

In your form you should ask for country and region ids:

```
<%= countries_form.collection_select(:id, Country.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Country') %>

<%= regions_form.collection_select(:id, Region.all, :id, :name, :prompt => 'Select Region') %>
```

In fact this is more difficult, because a region belongs to a country, but here you are showing all regions. You should only show regions for the selected country (which is dynamic).

Comment: thanks @Pablo  I do indeed have `Roast belongs_to :roaster` I think I left that out for brevity in other questions.  

Also, I am asking the user to insert values for `countries` and `regions` as I don't know all the possible values.  Once the database grows, I might well change this to be selected from their tables in the future. 

My issue here is now I can create a new Roast, but the Roaster is saved with some id value e.g. `#<Roaster:0x007fba9a43b500>` rather than the string.  I can see in the db table for Roasts, the Roaster column is blank.

Comment: I understand what you say about countries and regions. In the database for Roasts, the roaster column is roaster_id? Do you have anything else related to Roasts. You don't need `.permit(:roaster.....` in params. Just the roaster_id.

Comment: In the Roasts table, I have column for the name of the roaster which is `:roaster:char varying`, and also `:roaster_id:integer`. I can see in the able I am inserting an integer for the `roaster_id` but not a string for `roaster`.  I obviously want to display the `roaster:string` in my show view.

Comment: But the Roaster is in another table (you select the roaster in your form from the Roaster model and pass the roaster_id to the controller). You don't have to save the name in the Roast database. Just the roaster_id. The name is `@roast.roaster.name`

Comment: Ah of course! For some reason doing this from a select has confused me.  Still very much getting to grips with associated models.  It was in fact `@roast.roaster.roaster_name` in my show view that worked, but your point was correct.